# Insert into int8range from columns of another table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, range-types

I have two tables in PostgreSQL:

Table `indexces_grid`:

```
+---------------+------------+
| Column Name   | Type       |
+---------------+------------+
| indexid       | bigint     |
| iprange       | int8range  |
+---------------+------------+
```

Table `citydetails`:

```
+---------------+-----------+
| Column Name   | Type      |
+---------------+-----------+
| ipfrom        | bigint    |
| ipto          | bigint    |
| cityname      | varchar   |
+---------------+-----------+
```

I want to insert the `ipfrom` and `ipto` into the single column `iprange` of the `indexces_grid` table.

Answer (score 2):

It's so [simple](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/rangetypes.html):

```
INSERT INTO indexces_grid ("Row2")
SELECT int8range(ipfrom, ipto, '[]')
  FROM citydetails;
```

The documentation linked above tells you all.

Note that one has to use the three-parameter form of the range constructor function (here `int8range()`) to include the upper bound, too.  Using the two-parameter form, the upper bound would be non-inclusive.

I've created an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1bfd7/1) to show this at work.